# demo application issue with models and queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make one simple application but seems like facing issue. I have created many to many object between student and course and has also define dept.
My model is mentioned below:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    courseId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    courseName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    enrolledStu = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
         return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.courseName,self.enrolledStu,self.students,self.dept)

class Dept(models.Model):
    deptId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    deptName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
         return '%s %s' % (self.deptId, self.deptName)

class Student(models.Model):
    stuName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stuCity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stuPhone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    stuNationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stuCreatedt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.stuName,self.stuCity,self.stuNationality)
```

my form is :

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('stuName','stuCity','stuPhone','stuNationality','stuCreatedt')


class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('courseId','courseName','enrolledStu','students','dept')


class DeptForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dept
        fields = ('deptId','deptName')
```

I have displayed list of course , students and dept in html template now i am trying to edit it with code :

```
def edtStudent(request,pk):
    course = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept').get()
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = CourseForm(request.POST,instance=Course)
        if form.is_valid():
           course = form.save(commit=False)
           print(form.cleaned_data)
           course.courseName = request.POST['courseName']
           course.enrolledStu = request.Post['enrolledStu']
           course.save()
           course.save_m2m()
           return redirect('liststudent')
    else:
        print(course.__dict__)
        print(course.students)
        #form = CourseForm()
        #return render(request, 'stuApp/edtStudent.html', {'form':form})
        #form = CourseForm(instance=course[0]) worked
        form = CourseForm(instance=course)
        return render_to_response('stuApp/edtStudent.html', {'form': form})
```

so instead of getting one student i am getting all students for course.. Seems like my query is incorrect. Can you help with that..

Another question i have is how can i print values for objects in many to many relationship.. for now if i print course object i am getting results like

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000000000457ED68>, 'courseId': 1, 'courseName': 'Account', 'enrolledStu': 1, 'dept_id': 1, '_dept_cache': <Dept: 1 Finance>, '_prefetched_objects_cache': {'students': <QuerySet [<Student: Mamta Mumbai Indian>]>}}
```

..

so from Query Set i would like to take only student name...

Jordan

Comment: You don't seem to have described your problem. *Where* are you getting all students for the course? And of course if you print the course `__dict_`, you'll get the internal representation. Why are you doing that at all?

Comment: Hi Daniel ,  so when i try to print course and related student and dept for edit in html template it should bring only one student but my query bring list of students object and instead of text box it comes in listbox.i have used this query "course = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept').get()" .its my 1st issue & 2nd prb is to edit course object i would like to only change student name it brings all information.So according to me my query is wrong which brings all students with course.. basically  i want to edit student information in html template

Comment: But why would you expect to only see one student? You ask for the course and all its students, that's what you get. Which student would you want and how is Django supposed to know?

Comment: opps got it .. i supposed to edit student here i am editing course.. sorry my bad.. i got it now.. now question is i am getting values for course with query and inside it i am getting all students in queryset.

Comment: c = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept').get() and from c ,
c.students.values()
which will print <QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'stuName': 'jordan', 'stuCity': 'newyork', 'stuPhone': 123456789, 'stuNationality': 'british', 'stuCreatedt': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 11, 43, 25, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>
how to get only student name from queryset..

Comment: i figured it out i can use "course.students.value_list('stuName', flat=True) " to get value of only student name to edit.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have follow up question for this.. when i try to edit course for html template it gets the values which are correct ,but for student its gets all attribute like studentname , city , natinality etc.. which wrong.. i want only student name from student and display it in template.
I am using following query to get course related information.

```
course = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept').get()
```

[getting results from query but for student it gets all attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFmf7.png)

Now in my views i am using this code:

```
course = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept').get()
    form = CourseForm(instance=course)
    return render_to_response('stuApp/edtStudent.html', {'form': form})
```

i figured out how to get value for student name instead of all atributes.

```
course.students = course.students.value_list('stuName', flat=True)
```

but i am not sure how can i set above value to form and display it in template..
this where i am failing..